# Click and Reorder

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

Currently working on a click and reorder function that I could use some assistance with.

```
|         | list item 1
| content | list item 2
|         | list item 3
```

Essentially when you click one of the 3 list items, it then displays in the content box to the left of the list. After the item is then sorted into the content box, the list reorders.

```
| list item 2 | list item 1
|   content   | list item 3
|             |
```

What I have so far is:

```
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>

<script>
   jQuery("li").click(function() {
   jQuery(this).parent().prepend(jQuery(this)); 
});
</script>
```

Any insight would be extremely helpful. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an empty `ul` in your content area, assign a click handler to the `li`'s of the list you have, and on click, move the `li` to the `ul` in the content area.

```js
$('#plist li').on('click', function() {
  var $contentli = $('#contentli');
  $contentli.find('li').appendTo($('#plist'));
  $(this).prependTo('#contentli');
})
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="content">
  <ul id="contentli">
    <li>1</li>
  </ul>
  <h1>content</h1>
</div>

<ul id="plist">
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is really great. Thank you sincerely for the help. For arguments sake, say I prepend the second list item to the content div/list. But then I want to view the 6th list item. What I'm trying to accomplish now is a swap. So only the 6th item would be viewable in the content div/list and the second list item would return to its place in the list.

Comment: @Buckk no problem. Updated my answer to first find any `li`'s in the content list, and move them back to the product list before moving the `li` from the product list to the content list. Does that help?

Comment: Thank you so much! I don't know why I was overthinking it so much But sincerely thank you.

Comment: What if on page load, I wanted to have the first list item displayed in the content div and then swap the list items on click?

Comment: @Buckk I edited the answer - just removed the first item from the list and moved it to the content area. Is that what you're going for?

Comment: Yes, exactly! Thanks for all the help.